# Download csv file via HTTP handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, export-to-csv, ihttphandler

I got error using   `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();` when try to download **csv** file. 
I search for error and get solution . Use Handler to avoid `Response.End();`.

My handler :

```
public class DownloadHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string table = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["table"].ToString();
        string fileName = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["fileName"].ToString();
        table = table.Replace("&gt;", ">");
        table = table.Replace("&lt;", "<");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M_dd_yyyy_H_M_s") + ".csv");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table);

    }


    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I call this handler in button click like this.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("Mypath/DownloadHandler.ashx?table=" + csv + "&fileName=User-Report");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Its call the handler .I have no error but csv file is not downloaded ? I am unable to figure out where is a real problem. May  I missing something in code ? Thanks for help.

*Note: csv is a string comes from another process that's not a real problem.*

Comment: What you do after getting response ?

Comment: @dotnetstep nothing no error. just Stop a page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing HttpWebRequest then you have to request then getResponse. Read from response stream and save.

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:57169/DownloadHandler.ashx?table=tttex&fileName=User-Report");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        byte[] data = new System.IO.BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadBytes((int)response.ContentLength);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Temp.csv", data);
```

if you want browser to download then just do following thing.

```
  Response.Redirect("http://yourpath/DownloadHandler.ashx?table=tttex&fileName=User-Report");
```